# Is it legal C++ to declare main as extern "C"?

Tags: c++, program-entry-point, extern, linkage

Being a low-level programmer, I often work with the module startup code for executables, so I understand pretty well how code like "crt0" work.  When writing C++ code, I've generally declared `main` as `extern "C"` to match what the C startup code is going to do to call `main`.  I thus usually use this declaration for `main` (and `wmain` if specifically targeting Windows):

```
extern "C" int main(int argv, const char *const *argv)

extern "C" int __cdecl wmain(int argv, const wchar_t *const *argv)
```

Is it legal to use `extern "C"` on `main`?  Also, is `const char *const *` legal for argv's type as opposed to `char *[]`?

Comment: `const char *const *argv` should be legal, though you might want to keep it at `char *const *argv` for practical reasons, specifically the fact that if you ever use getopt or similar, that first const will kill you.

Comment: You don't actually want the C startup code. You need to run the constructors of globals to run, and that's done by the C++ startup code. The other way around, usually no problems exist. There's nothing in the C language that causes problems for C++ startup code.

Comment: See also [What should `main()` return in C and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The linkage is implementation defined (3.6.1p3):

> The linkage (3.5) of main is implementation-defined.

Also, for your latter question, that is perfectly acceptable to have `const char* const*` (3.6.1p2):

> An implementation shall not predefine the main function. This function
>   shall not be overloaded. It shall have a return type of type int, but
>   otherwise its type is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 5):

`extern "C"` only tells the C++ compiler specifically to NOT decorate or use name wrangling on generated function labels.

Yes, both are legal.

Comment: Actually, it can also change the calling convention: default C++ calling convention doesn't have to be compatible with the C one, only `extern "C"` enforces that.

Comment: "default C++ calling convention doesn't have to be compatible with the C one", really? any citation? To my knowledge, being compatible with C is one of the main aims of C++. @syam

Answer (score 4):

The standard blesses two forms of `main`:

```
int main()
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

These forms are what any implementation must recognize. Everything else is your implementation being easy with your code and letting you be creative. It is not illegal, as the standard specifically allows it to recognize other forms of `main`.

The startup code is normally written in a way that allows it to call `main` having no linkage declaration, because that's how the standard says `main` should be. The compiler usually treats `main` specially as having C linkage, as allowed by the standard, so that's how the startup code declares it. This is of no interest to a normal programmer. He just needs to follow the standard.

Comment: Windows in particular seems to treat `main()` as `extern "C" void __cdecl main()`, and the MS-specific `WinMain()` as `extern "C" void __stdcall WinMain()`, judging by the mangled names (`_main` and `_WinMain@16`, respectively).  I suspect it's a limitation of the CRT being designed to work with both C and C++ code.  [`wmain` and `wWinMain` are treated identically to `main` and `WinMain`.]